# How to define Grafana dashboard variable as a subset of another variable?

Tags: variables, grafana

I have a variable in Grafana dashboard that allows multiple values. I need a subset of the values to use in the *Repeat for* box of Row options. To solve this problem I'm trying to create another variable that will select needed subset of values from the source one.

The source variable is of type *Custom* with *Multi-value* option selected. The *Values separated by comma* are, lets say, "A1, B1, A2, B2".

How to define an alias for this variable, that has the same values and the "Multi-value" property? The follow up question is how to define a variable that selects a subset of values (for example the values that start with "A")?

I'm using Grafana 8.1.3

Comment: As @alparius has mentioned: send it to SQL datasource and do a business logic there, e.g. `SELECT '${variable:raw}'` or e.g. Redshift SQL `SELECT TRIM(SPLIT_PART('${variable:raw}', ',', 0))` - selects first array item from string splited by `,`. Remember you need to return multiple rows if you want to have multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

This might be bit of a hack, and I'm not sure I fully understand your problem (your question could use better explained examples), but I think both cases can be solved by creating query-typed variables on your default datasource, but actually just querying your original variable.

- In case of SQL, it is as simple as: `SELECT '$myvar'`. Not sure how it works with other query languages. And probably you can solve it from there.
- Similarly, you can incorporate Grafana variables into other variables (for example in the where part to create dependencies between them).
- Or you can hide variables if you don't want your users to interact with them, by not filling the *Label* field, and selecting to *Hide* the Variable.

Comment: I'm probably missing details, but the query like `SELECT '${myvar}'` defines the only value `None`. I tried all datasources available in my Grafana.

Comment: This one can be used only on an SQL datasource, which I assumed you have. On the `--Grafana--` etc datasources it returns none/timeout for me as well.

Comment: So looks like there are no SQL connections in my setup.

Comment: Some similar query might or might not be possible in other languages. We have still no idea what are you using. Setting up a mock SQL db for this alone might be overkill though.